# RegionPlot3D with RegionPlot in the same graph

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

I'd like to use RegionPlot3D to show a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ and, in the same plot, indicate a subset of the $xy$-plane using RegionPlot.  How would I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the absence of a specific example from the OP, here's something I did previously:

```
p1 = RegionPlot[x^2 + y^3 < 2, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, BoundaryStyle -> ColorData[97, 3],
                PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.3, ColorData[97, 3]]];
p2 = RegionPlot3D[x^2 + y^3 < z + 2, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2}, 
                  Mesh -> False, PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.2]];

Show[p2, Graphics3D[MapAt[PadRight[#, {Automatic, 3}] &, 
                          First[Cases[p1, _GraphicsComplex, ∞]], 1]]]
```

[image: 2D and 3D regions together]

Comment: I won't pretend I understand that code, but it worked perfectly.  Thank you!